# Powershell Script to loop through folders checking security permissions

Tags: security, powershell, csv, permissions, acl

I have part of the code: at the moment its coming empty in the CSV file. But i need a command to specify the path/folders to look at, how do i modify this for that purpose.

```
Param(
    [String]$path,
    [String]$outfile = ".\outfile.csv"
)

$output = @()

ForEach ($item in (Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Directory)) {

    ForEach ($acl in ($item.GetAccessControl().Access)){

        $output += $acl | 
            Add-Member `
                -MemberType NoteProperty `
                -Name 'Folder' `
                -Value $item.FullName `
                -PassThru

    }

}

$output | Export-Csv -Path $outfile -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: It's not quite clear to me what your question is here. You already have a parameter `$Path` that allows you to specify a base folder. Please provide an example of the desired result.

Comment: I have managed to resolve it with a few changes to the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's do this. I've made it into a function, and removed the OutFile part of it. If you want to output it to a file, pipe it to `Export-CSV`. If you want it saved as a variable, assign it to a variable. Just simpler this way.

```
Function Get-RecursiveACLs{
Param(
    [String]$Path=$(Throw "You must specify a path")
)

    $Output = GCI $Path -Recurse -Directory|%{
        $PathName=$_.FullName
        $_.GetAccessControl().Access|%{
            Add-Member -InputObject $_ -NotePropertyName "Path" -NotePropertyValue $PathName -PassThru
        }
    }
}
```

Then it's a simple matter of storing it in a variable like:

```
$ACLList = Get-RecursiveACLs "C:\Example\Path"
```

Or piping it to output to a CSV if you would prefer:

```
Get-RecursiveACLs "C:\Example\Path" | Export-CSV "C:\Results.csv" -NoType
```

Put the function at the top of your script and call it as needed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I have gone on to resolving it with the code.